# VSCode visual bleeding and overall slow down on Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been experiencing a heavy slow down while using VSCode (while navigating, scrolling, marking). There may be many causes, but even more interesting are the occuring visual bleeds.
Maybe someone already stumbled upon this problem.

My current setup is a tower computer with Windows 11 and a RTX 3060 TI as GPU.

Some examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like your gpu needs an update to me, but you haven't said whether you're using a pc laptop or a macbook pro

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated my gpu drivers to the latest version.
I'm using a tower pc with Windows 11.